# Write to SQLite database from XML data

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite, xamarin.ios

Given the following code to export each table in the database:

```
string strSql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
SqliteConnection sqlCon = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath);

using (SqliteCommand sqlComm = new SqliteCommand(strSql, sqlCon) { CommandType = CommandType.Text })
{
    var da = new SqliteDataAdapter(sqlComm);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    ds.Tables[0].WriteXml(Path.Combine(syncPath, tableName + "_4.xml"));
}
```

I'm trying to import the XML back into the database with the following:

```
SqliteConnection sqlCon = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dataPath + "/Empty.db3");
sqlCon.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Path.Combine(syncPath, tableName + "_4.xml"));

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
string keyField = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns[keyField] };

var adapterForTable1 = new SqliteDataAdapter("Select * from " + tableName, sqlCon);
adapterForTable1.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
var builderForTable1 = new SqliteCommandBuilder(adapterForTable1);
adapterForTable1.Update(ds, tableName);

sqlCon.Close();
```

But I get the error: `Dynamic SQL generation is not supported with no base table.` How do I fix this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a generated xml file in your question. Also, what is the line that throws the exception?

Comment: adapterForTable1.Update(ds, tableName); is where the error is generated.

Comment: <NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <activityItemID>4aa053cd-e4b4-4ec9-9c10-782b0e40aeee</activityItemID>
    <activityID>44f298b2-55c0-4739-be81-6ad26969f237</activityID>
    <iconID>3e4393e5-78e5-4f9a-9caf-d4df5af3f324</iconID>
    <columnNum>2</columnNum>
    <rowNum>1</rowNum>
    <modStamp>2012-11-21T00:36:05</modStamp>
  </Table>...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abandoned the Update option and wrote this:

```
SqliteConnection sqlCon = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dataPath + "/Empty.db3");
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqliteCommand sqlCmd = new SqliteCommand(sqlCon);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(Path.Combine(syncPath, tableName + "_4.xml"), XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
            foreach(DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                //Get field names
                string sqlString = "INSERT into " + tableName + " (";
                string valString = "";
                var sqlParams = new string[dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.Count()];
                int count = 0;
                foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sqlString += dc.ColumnName + ", ";
                    valString += "@" + dc.ColumnName + ", ";
                    sqlParams[count] = "@" + dc.ColumnName;
                    count++;
                }
                valString = valString.Substring(0, valString.Length - 2);
                sqlString = sqlString.Substring(0, sqlString.Length - 2) + ") VALUES (" + valString + ")";

                sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlString;
                foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dr.ItemArray.Count(); i++) 
                    {
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(sqlParams[i], dr.ItemArray[i] ?? DBNull.Value);
                    }

                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just in case someone uses the above generating code, the following line should be added in the beginning of the for loop sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();