# Programmatically acess (c#) internet explorer chrome history in windows 10 64 bit

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, internet-explorer

I want to index all the user actions and websites in Internet explorer. i understand that internet explorer index all the data in sqlLite database. how can i Programmatically access the internet explorer web history in my own application

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source= C:\Users\47\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata ");
conn.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
// cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;";
// Use the above query to get all the table names
cmd.CommandText = "select url,title,visit_count,datetime(last_visit_time / 1000000 + (strftime('%s', '1601-01-01')), 'unixepoch'),typed_count from urls order by last_visit_time desc";
//"Select * From urls order by last_visit_time desc";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0].ToString(),dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString());
}
```

i tried the above code but the getting an exception like

> System.Data.SQLiteException{"SQL logic error or missing database\r\nno
>   such table: urls"}

i just trued some other location like C:\Users\47\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Recovery those also not working 
i think this is because of IE history location or table name...

Comment: under this path I only see a XML which includes which sites gets emulated for older IE versions. why do you think IE uses SQLite?

Comment: I really don't know I got the URL history from IE using SQLite. and I didn't find any other solution

Comment: look here for history: C:\Users\47\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History

Comment: i tried C:\Users\47\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History this location and getting exception   {"unable to open database file"}

Comment: again, IE doesn't use SQLite

Comment: can you suggest any other solution

Answer (score 0):

Your SQLite connection is wrong. The data source you pointed to isn't an SQLite file - it's an XML file. The SQLite extension is `sqlitedatabse.db`.

You should do this step:
Create a SQLite database and then export data from XML file to your SQLite database, like in this link: [how to export data from XML to sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085365/write-to-sqlite-database-from-xml-data)

Comment: instead of that is there any database for IE and can I fetch details directly

Comment: you know you can read XML file directly without any database this solution is available sure